# Mathematica implementation of meshgrid in 3D

Tags: plotting

Mathematica implementation of meshgrid in 2D is

```
meshgrid[x_List, y_List]:={ConstantArray[x,Length[x]],Transpose@ConstantArray[y,Length[y]]}.
```

**Can any one help to have Mathematica meshgrid in 3D**

Answer (score 3):

You may use the following for any dimension:

```
meshgrid[x__?VectorQ] := Reverse[Transpose[Tuples[Reverse[{x}]]]]
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to test it with Matlab at the moment.

Comment: How can I fix this code  using your comments, please help                                                                    
  meshgrid[x_List, y_List, z_list] := {ConstantArray[x, Length[x]], 
  Transpose@ConstantArray[y, Length[y]], 
  Transpose@ConstantArray[z, Length[z]]}
{xx, yy, zz} = 
 meshgrid[Range[-2, 2, .1], Range[-4, 4, .2], Range[-6, 6, .2] ]
c = xx*Exp[-xx^2 - yy^2] + 2 zz;
pts = Flatten[{xx, yy, zz, c}];
ListPlot3D[pts, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
 ImagePadding -> 20, Mesh -> 35, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Boxed -> False]