# How to sample numerically a function using a mesh-grid function in 3D?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, numerics, mesh

I am working on a problem where I want to sample a scalar function f[x,y,z].

The problem is how to obtain a mesh-grid in 3D (A grid of points in x,y, and z). In order to study this function.

Of course, I´ve read previous questions in 2D [Simulate MATLAB's meshgrid function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30701/simulate-matlabs-meshgrid-function). And also an incomplete answered was reported here [Mathematica implementation of meshgrid in 3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186869/mathematica-implementation-of-meshgrid-in-3d).

Please, How can I solve and fix this code?

```
 Clear["Global`*"];
  meshgrid[x_List, y_List, z_list] := {ConstantArray[x, Length[x]], 
  Transpose@ConstantArray[y, Length[y]], 
  Transpose@ConstantArray[z, Length[z]]}
 {xx, yy, zz} = 
 meshgrid[Range[-2, 2, .1], Range[-4, 4, .2], Range[-6, 6, .2] ]
c = xx*Exp[-xx^2 - yy^2] + 2 zz;
pts = Flatten[{xx, yy, zz, c}];
ListPlot3D[pts, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
 ImagePadding -> 20, Mesh -> 35, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Boxed -> False]
```

**The code output is**

Set::shape: Lists {xx,yy,zz} and meshgrid[{-2.,-1.9,-1.8,-1.7,-1.6,-1.5,-1.4,-1.3,-1.2,-1.1,-1.,-0.9,-0.8,-0.7,-0.6,-0.5,-0.4,-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,0.,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2.},{-4.,-3.8,<<38>>,4.},{-6.,-5.8,-5.6,<<45>>,3.6,3.8,<<11>>}] are not the same shape.

ListPlot3D: {xx,yy,zz,2.71828^(-1. xx^2-1. yy^2) xx+2. zz} must be a valid array or a list of valid arrays.

Comment: Try to search stackexchange for meshgrid 3D...

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann. This problem has not been explained before, I have searched where you recommend me.  indeed I  also put the links related to my questions (look them up).

Comment: @irondonio, `Flatten[Table[{xx,yy,zz,c},{xx,-2,2,0.1},{yy,-4,4,0.2},{zz,-6,6,0.2}],2]` gives you tabulated values of function `c` at grid points in 3D. Then you may visualize this with `ListDensityPlot3D`.

Comment: "This problem has not been explained before" perhaps because this problem has not been explained before -- that is, no one asking the question has taken the trouble to describe what the problem is, what `meshgrid` does.

Answer (score 2):

This might work better:

```
{xx, yy, zz} = Transpose[Tuples[{Range[-2, 2, .1], Range[-4, 4, .2], Range[-6, 6, .2]}]];
c = xx*Exp[-xx^2 - yy^2] + 2 zz;
pts = Transpose[{xx, yy, zz, c}];
```

In the end you try to plot a 4D-list with ListPlot3D. That is not possible. Instead, you may use

```
ListDensityPlot3D[pts,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
 ]
```

[image]

or

```
ListSliceDensityPlot3D[pts,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
 ]
```

[image]

However, if you want to plot only the function ``, then you don't have to mess around with meshes anyways. You can simply use

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[
 x*Exp[-x^2 - y^2] + 2 z,
 {x, -2, 2},
 {y, -4, 4},
 {z, -6, 6},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Henrik Schumacher, I can't understand your proposal is very advanced for my knowledge in Mathematica  Please,  could you be so kind as to take a minute and show the complete solution.   You're right I can't graph using ListPlot3D. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking for "meshgrid 3d" in stackexchange gives a bunch of answers

One of them "Creating a three dimensional grid" offers

```
meshgrid3D[xxx_List, yyy_List, zzz_List] := Table[#, {x, xxx}, {y, yyy}, {z, zzz}] & /@ {x, y, z}
```

as Mathematica version of *matlab meshgrid*

Comment: Thanks@Ulrich Neumann,  I implemented your code  but it doesn't work      meshgrid3D[xxx_List, yyy_List, zzz_List] := 
 Table[c, {x, xxx}, {y, yyy}, {z, zzz}] & /@ {x, y, z} {xxx, yyy, zzz} = {Range[-2, 2, .1], Range[-4, 4, .2], 
   Range[-6, 6, .2]};
c = xx*Exp[-xx^2 - yy^2] + zz; What it still wrong ? Thanks

Comment: There is nothing wrong. What you call `c` evaluates to a matrix of same size as `xx,yy,zz`. The question remains why you want to use meshgrid formalism from matlab, which is matrix orientated. List -concept of Mathematica is much more easy to apply I think!

Comment: ...from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115048/4999) by @JasonB. (["And always give proper credit to the author and site [sic] where you found the text, **including a direct link to it.**"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/referencing))